# how to find checkbox where checked in repeater in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

i  want   when  click  btndelete ,  every  checkbox  where  chechek  in  repeater1  to  get   value  of  column(titr)  in  same  row,  but  i  dont  find  which  checkbox  checked  and dont  access  to  value of  column(titr)

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>subject</td>

                    </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                              </td>
                              <td id="checkvalue" >
                                  <%# Eval("titr") %>
                              </td>


                          </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

 <asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" Text="delete" OnClick="btndelete_Click" />
```

.cs code is :

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  Despite grammar/language, it is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: it is my bad Chance

Answer (score 3):

You could get a list of repeaterItems for each row in which the checkbox is checked using linq such that:

```
    List<RepeaterItem> selectedItems = Repeater1.Items.Cast<RepeaterItem>().Where(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl("CheckBox1"))
.Checked).ToList();
```

You could then iterate through the list and get the value of titr for each of the selected rows, but you would have to set some server control equal to "titr" when you bind the control, like:

```
<asp:literal id="literal1" runat="server"><%# Eval("titr") %></asp:literal>
```

That way you could go find the value later when you iterate through the list, like this:

```
List<string> titrValues = selectedItems.Select(t => ((Literal)t.FindControl("literal1).Text));
```

You may have to do some tweaking, but that should get you the values of titr for each row with a selected value.

Answer (score 3):

Aspx Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CategoryID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("val") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button Text="Click" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              dt.Rows.Add("testing" + i.ToString());

       Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
       Repeater1.DataBind();
           }
        }     

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string Rpt = "Repeater Items Checked:<br />";
                for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CategoryID");
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        Rpt += (chk.Text + "<br />");
                    }
                }
                Response.Write(Rpt);
            }
```

You can also use break point to check the get values....

Refrenced By: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/534719/GetplusSelectedplusCheckboxesplusinplusASPplusRepe